# Inspiration for Iain M. Banks' Inversions?

Tags: inspiration, the-culture

Following some discussion on a private forum about the [Culture series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series) by Iain M. Banks, I found myself thinking that the science fiction novel [Inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversions_(novel)) shared some interesting similarities with the Umberto Eco's (non scifi) novel *[The Name of the Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Rose)*. In short, the similarities I found are the medieval setting (pseudo-medieval in the case of Inversions); one of the protagonists championing humanism/reason against obscurantism; and the narrator being a "protégé" of the said protagonist.

Of course, there are obvious differences too, and similarities don't necessarily mean that Iain M. Banks actually found his inspiration in the Umberto Eco's novel.

However it made me wonder if Iain M. Banks ever stated if his novel was inspired by other authors (or possibly, artists, film directors, etc.). I'm particularly interested in the possible inspirations for the "Doctor" character in *Inversions*.

After a quick online search about it, I didn't find anything about it in the couple of IMB interviews I found. But of course this is entirely possible that I missed some interesting information, or that some information about it is unavailable online. That's why I ask this question here. Thanks.

Comment: The Strugatsky brothers' book *Hard to Be a God* also has plenty of similarities (basic story is about members of a utopian post-scarcity society infiltrating a medieval society), but I haven't found any direct evidence Banks had read it.

Comment: I have no insight into what Banks may have been influenced by, but another possible model for an anachronistically enlightened female doctor caught up the the political manoeuvring of a SFnal medieval setting is Cynthia, from John M Ford's "The Dragon Waiting: A Masque of History" (1984).  Another possibility is Jehane bet Ishak in Guy Gavriel Kay's "The Lions of Al-Rassan" (1995).